# image picker controller takes insane memory even if released

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

my image picker is initialized like:

> self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
>
> self.imgPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
>
> self.imgPicker.delegate = self;
>
> self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

presentation:

> [self initImagePickerFromLibrary]; ----(this calls the lines I have mentioned before)
>
> ```
>       [self presentModalViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES];
>
>
>       [imgPicker release];
> ```

apple instrument says:
before calling the picker memory used is 3 Mb.While the picker is in function 12Mb.While editing image is 28Mb and my app crashes.Anyone did find a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one thing that comes to mind is that you're doing `self.` which may mean that your image picker is retained twice. Once, because you're allocating it and once because you're using a setter.

What does the `@property` line look like for `imgPicker`? Does it have `retain`? If it does, you should either change the first line in your first quote above to:

```
imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
```

I.e. removing `self.`.

Also in your second line, you're releasing `imgPicker` directly. If your `@property` does have retain, you should instead just do:

```
self.imgPicker = nil;
```

The reason is that the `@property` synthesizing retains and releases objects when you set them. If you `release` the `imgPicker` without setting it to `nil`, and then, later on, try to set it to a new value, the system will attempt to `release` the already released object, and probably crash. The above is the same as doing:

```
[imgPicker release];
imgPicker = nil;
```